# Intellij Idea Kotlin plugin cannot see scala case class accessors

Tags: scala, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm using kotlin with akka and after kotlin plugin update, I'm facing issues with IDE errors:
It has "error" severity like compilation error, but it compiles just fine.
Is it possible to somehow get rid of it? I was not able to downgrade kotlin plugin (maybe help with that).
Im using intellij 2020.1.1 with kotlin plugin 1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-3

[image]

scala class:

```scala
final class EventEnvelope(
    val offset: Offset,
    val persistenceId: String,
    val sequenceNr: Long,
    val event: Any,
    val timestamp: Long)
```

Comment: Do you have Scala plugin installed? Scala has `public` as default and package-private has to be set up explicitly - if IDE sees Scala files as Kotlin files it might give you a wrong intellisense.

Comment: of course i have scala plugin installed in version: 2020.1.29

Comment: Hah...new observation: i realized, when scala plugin is disabled, its no longer showing compilation problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Kotlin IDEA plugin bug on IDEA version 2020.1. Please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38273 for updates.

Workarounds: use IDEA 2019.3 or disable IDEA Scala plugin.